# Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag freezes on start

Tags: technical-issues, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

When I start the AC4, at the loading hud freeze and the program stops working.
I've similar problem in [this steam community thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/242050/discussions/0/558748822711618462).

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you also post your PC's specs, as this would a help us with ruling out certain possibilities

Comment: Core I5, 12GB Ram, GTX 1030 2GB

Comment: Have you already uninstalled it and reinstalled?